# Why don't airliners use full throttle on takeoff?

Tags: takeoff

It seems that you would use full power for takeoffs, but when I have heard of airline pilots using less than full power on takeooff. Wouldn't it be safer to use full throttle?

Comment: See: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/is-it-possible-that-derated-thrust-takeoffs-are-safer-than-normal-takeoffs

Comment: ah, I didn't see that question. just voted to close this one